# Do we have a way to check if an element already exists in HyperLogLog in Java

Tags: java, hyperloglog

I have a use case where I need to check if an element already exists in the Hyperloglog and if not, I need to make a hbase call. Do we have any method IN JAVA to check if element already exists in HyperLogLog

Comment: What implementation of HLL are you using?

Comment: private static HLL hllActiveUsersWithPID = new HLL(14,5);
    HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.murmur3_128(); This is the use case

Comment: Is that a library you're using? https://github.com/aggregateknowledge/java-hll

Comment: yes that is the library I am using

Comment: You can add an element and check whether cardinality has changed or not. If it changed, then HLL didn't contain this element

Answer (score 1):

HyperLogLog is not suitable for checking element memberships. Use a Bloom filter, if you need a compact data structure for approximative set membership testing. More recent, but more complicated alternatives would be Cuckoo, XOR, or Ribbon filters.